# GET request of an object from server

Tags: javascript, node.js, http

I'm using vanilla Javascript with Node (HTTP) for server side and XMLHttpRequest for client side.
Not sure how i could send an object that i've read on the server to the client.

For example i've this server code, to read the data and store it on data array to send later to the client:

```
            data = []
            fs.readFile("./client.json", function(err, jsonData){
                if(err){
                    throw err;
                }else{
                    data.push(JSON.parse(jsonData));
                }
            });
```

Now i'm kinda lost of how client side would be to GET the data array.
I've tried this but couldn't get any

```
let xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhttp.open("GET", "http://localhost:3000/data", true);
    xhttp.send(null);
```

I don't want to use Fetch nor Express. using HTTP for learning purpose.

Comment: Have you created the GET API? If yes, please share the api code.

Comment: I'm not sure what do you mean by GET API, i don't think i've created it

Comment: What I can only see is you reading a json file and pushing the data to an array, but i can't see the `data` endpoint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **URL** module to parse *request URL*  to write logic for individual endpoints.

In your case the endpoint would be `/data`. Here you can return the data array as response.

Refer [URL | Node.js](https://nodejs.org/api/url.html)